# Как реализовать добавление в корзину товара с опциями?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]Как можно на React js и redux реализовать функцию, которая добавляет один товар с разными опциями в корзину?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Конкретизируйте вопрос, что именно у вас не получается? Добавить элемент в список? Хранить список, передавать его? Приведите пример кода и опишите что не так он делает.

Comment: Я не понимаю как построить такой компонент ибо я новичок. Понятно как добавлять товары без опций в корзину, но тут другая история. Тут надо добавить товар с выбранными опциями, но чтобы была возможность добавить этот же товар с другими опциями

Comment: Какой компонент, товар в корзине - это всего лишь обьект в списке обьектов, а не компонент. компонент реакта - это то что отрисовано для  пользователя, вот этот вот прямоугольик с картинками. При нажатии на кнопку добавить в этом компоненте в список(корзину) добавляется простой  js  обьект. Так вот вы компоненты реакта не можете создать? Не знаете как по клику сделать событие? Как инициализировать обьект и добавить его в список?

Comment: Я знаю как добавить объект в корзину. Но тут допустим я хочу добавить одну пиццу двух размеров, нпример: 30 см. и 40 см. Я уже догадался как такое добавлять в корзину, но не знаю как подсчитать их количество.

Comment: тогда приведите код, как добавляется товар, мы сможем подсказать как его изменить чтоб товар имел опции.

Comment: Картинки в добавил в вопрос

Comment: @РоманАхмедов Код лучше приводить именно кодом, а не картинками

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш обьект который вы добавляете в корзину содержит только информацию о товаре на карточке, вы хотите добавть "опции" - они не отображаются на карточке а идут отдельно списком к пицце. Вам необходимо в обьект product  добавить еще одно поле, содержащее массив опций.

То есть если примерно так:

```
    const product = {
      id = card.id
      price = card.price

      options = card.options
}
```

Comment: А где в карточке будут формироваться опции и как присавиваться - для ответа на этот вопрос приведите больше кода описывающего  card  и его поведение. Только пожалуйста не картинки, просто скопируйте код